# In GWT RPC, How to send raw deserialized response object to client?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I know this is a bit hacky but current circumstances can't allow me to rewrite certain aspects of the application.

```
rpcService.someServiceCall(String someParameter,
            new AsyncCallback<LargeClientObject>(){
```

Basically, we have a very large response from the server to client called LargeClientObject.  The deserialization on the client side is taking a very long time to unmarshal.  I was wondering what the best way would be to send deserialized data (raw JSON) to the client so that the client doesn't have to waste time deserializing it.

I was wondering if there was a way to simply do:

```
rpcService.someServiceCall(String someParameter,new ASyncCallback_WithNoClientSerialization<LargeClientObject>(){
```

FYI,I've tried using RequestFactory to load ClientObjects but it has many custom objects which would take forever to write RequestProxies for and I'd have to refactor most of the existing application.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may consider two approaches.

A. Call a servlet to get a,JSON response without using RPC.

B. Use the existing RPC service but change the return type to String instead of LargeClientObject, and pass a JSON string.

You probably have to test which approach works better.